# Npgsql Entity Framework Core is returning duplicated rows from view

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I'm trying to retrieve some rows from a view. The view is getting data from three tables.
Three columns are involved in the problem: `id_product` is comming from one table, `id_article` is comming from another table and finally we have `rohling_code` comming from a third table. We can say that the index for this table is formed by these three columns. For some records, `id_product` and `id_article` could have equal values and only `rohling_code` is different. I'm trying to retrieve the records using this statement:

```cs
var query = from substrate in _dbContext.Substrates
               join customer_articles in _dbContext.CustomerArticles on substrate.IdSubstrate equals 
                    customer_articles.ArticleId
               where customer_articles.ClientNumber == clientId
               select substrate;
```

With this statement I'm getting a list containing the correct number of records, but, the column `rohling_code` is not correctly fulfilled, as an example:

```
| id_article | id_product | rohling_code |
------------------------------------------ 
| 1234       | 7654       | 11           |
------------------------------------------
| 1234       | 7654       | 11           |
------------------------------------------
| 1234       | 7654       | 11           |
------------------------------------------
| 6754       | 8820       | 66           |
------------------------------------------
....
```

Instead of something similar to:

```
| id_article | id_product | rohling_code |
------------------------------------------ 
| 1234       | 7654       | 11           |
------------------------------------------
| 1234       | 7654       | 15           |
------------------------------------------
| 1234       | 7654       | 21           |
------------------------------------------
| 6754       | 8820       | 66           |
------------------------------------------
....
```

I tried this SQL against the view in PGSQL:

```sql
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    portal_data.v_substrates vs
JOIN portal_data.customer_articles c ON c.article_id = vs.id_substrate
WHERE c.id_customer = 1;
```

The records are returned as expected:

```
| id_article | id_product | rohling_code |
------------------------------------------ 
| 1234       | 7654       | 11           |
------------------------------------------
| 1234       | 7654       | 15           |
------------------------------------------
| 1234       | 7654       | 21           |
------------------------------------------
| 6754       | 8820       | 66           |
------------------------------------------
....
```

I tried also to run the above SQL command with the `FromSql()` EF Core method and the data is always duplicated on the `rohling_code` column.

I don't know if this is a bug on the Npgsql library or I'm doing something wrong instead.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Cross-posted as https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/2910#issuecomment-1774938760